# run code if NOT iPad

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, user-agent

```
if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('/iPadi') != -1) ) {

}
```

I use this if statement to detect if user agent is iPad but I only want to run code if it is **not** iPad. I have JQuery hover that i want to use in all cases except iPad, where I want to use touch gestures. In this case I would put the `hover()` function in and if statement to run only if **not** iPad.

Comment: Don't use user agents. Instead, use feature detection ([Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#touch) makes this easy) to determine if the browser supports touch events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my project I use this and it works. No need for regex:

```
  if ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') == -1 )
  {

  }
```

Comment: if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('/iPadi') = -1) ) {

}  I was trying with one equal sign why did that not work?

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, `==` is the comparison operator

Answer (score 0):

u want to use a regex.

`if ( (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) <= 0) ) {`

Answer (score 0):

This statement will do the job as well:

```
var isIpad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
```